# addthis sharing some facebook async issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, addthis

The problem is somehow connected with [Javascript: load AddThis upon clicking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6287119/javascript-load-addthis-upon-clicking), but not really the same.

So I have some content uploading with AJAX.
There I have a new AddThis toolbox with the correct code, just as I have in other places, white are loaded statically and work fine.

When I update my content I call `addthis.toolbox()` which generates the toolbox from the code, but Facebook button does not work, and Twitter and `.addthis_button_compact` work.
I use the very simple compact buttons style.
Does not work http://d.pr/i/K1QH - nor upon hover, nor upon click (loaded dynamically).
Works fine on hover http://d.pr/i/OilR - loaded statically

Unfortunately cannot show it on the live site - but it is just like in the example http://jsfiddle.net/beshur/mjncS/ ( and here it works)

Any ideas?
Or put it another way: Is there a way just to open a new window on click on the Facebook icon (like it happens with Twittwe) ? Just the simple sharer link.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're getting the hover because you're logged into AddThis.  That window is the Instant Share feature.  If you log out of AddThis, that should go away and work the way you expect it.